# Multivariable Calculus of form f(x, y)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to answer question 4ii)
[image]

This is my working out:
[image]

Checking the answers in the back of the book, I am incorrect. What am I doing wrong? I have only just started reading about Multi-Variable Calculus about an hour ago, teaching it to myself, so please don't be too harsh if I'm being a complete idiot.

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun thanks for the link, I'll use that in future. Is my writing that illegible though?

Comment: You're welcome. I can read your writing at least. Don't worry about it. You're new here :)

Comment: @Shaun given you can read my writing... any chance you could help me? ;)

Comment: Can you expand your acronyms? Not everyone is in the same locality as you,

Comment: @MatthewLeingang acronyms such as...?

Comment: In particular, MEI and FP3.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang "MEI" is the exam board I am on in England, and "FP3" is the module that this question is from

Comment: I'd love to, @talfred, but I have my own mathematics problems to solve. They have deadlines. Good luck :)

Comment: I know that. I'm asking you to edit your question to make it more accessible.  After all, you want to remove as many barriers as you can between the problem and the people who could potentially help you solve it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I have edited the title.